# VSIX Open a Comparison/Difference View Window

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio Extension for Visual Studio 2022 where I just want to Open a Comparison Window just like when you click on a file in the Git Changes view.

I see various classes IWpfDifferenceViewerFactoryService sounds promising but have found zero examples on how to use this class, especially when called from a Command Extension.
Same goes for IDifferenceViewer & 2, & 3.

I also see that the VS.Document.OpenAsync class of the Community Toolkit uses the VsShellUtilities class which is another can of worms and doesn't seem to have any Differencing capabilities.

If anyone has any idea how to do this, please let me know.  Sorry for the lack of code in my question, but I've googled the heck out of this to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is exactly what you had in mind, but Mads Kristensen (PM on the Visual Studio team @ Microsoft) has a sample "FileDiffer" extension for VS 2022:

https://github.com/madskristensen/FileDiffer/tree/master/src

The VS Command that does the diffing is here: https://github.com/madskristensen/FileDiffer/blob/master/src/Commands/DiffFilesCommand.cs

Comment: Ha, yes, I had recently come across this one too.  Seems it's possible with the mystical DTE commands.  I will give it a go.